# What is causing water collection on inside of concrete ceiling

Tags: condensation, wet, damp

This is a picture from the inside of a 1970's concrete build house in the UK; as far as I can tell there is no cavity wall (definitely no insulation) so that both walls and ceiling are exterior facing (there is a felt roof covering above exterior of ceiling).

During the winter, seemingly not strongly correlated to rainfall, water collects on the ceiling on the side of rooms closest to outer walls of building. It gets bad enough for droplets to form (see picture) and drip - water also trickles down the walls. This usually happens late afternoon into the evening and overnight.

[image] [image] [image]

What is causing this - is it condensation from humidity inside the rooms? Although this problem is also occurring in rooms that are less used. Is it condensation from external moisture, then seeping through to interior surfaces? What can be done to control / reduce / remove(!) this?

Thanks for your advice.

Edit - we've had a mould and moisture specialist visit, who tells us this **is** condensation. He had a machine with metal prongs that penetrate the inner walls and ceiling and apparently showed lower moisture content the deeper they went. So I guess the question pivots to how this issue can be controlled...?

Comment: This looks much more like water is getting in from the outside. Concrete is very porous, as is breeze-block (aka cinderblock). Often this happens when water is getting in from the roof and trickles down the walls until it reaches a ceiling and runs along joists and beams inside the property. Has it rained recently where you are?

Comment: It is winter, so it's certainly rained recently. I would say, however, that the damp spots appear on days where it hasn't necessarily rained. This started back in November, however, when the weather turned. What can be done to prove that it is coming from the exterior - and how can this problem be repaired?

Comment: If it *is* condensation, add insulation (hard to do if you don't own the flat), run a dehumidifier, or turn up the heat. Cut down on sources of moisture, such as boiling food or unvented showers.

Comment: Where should insulation be added? Can this only be done if there is a cavity between an inner and outer roof? Can it be put between the concrete roof and the felt cover?